# Setting Firebase Firestore to only allow read/write from a single Unity App

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've been looking for this answer for a while and honestly there isn't a lot of Firebase using Unity tutorials out that that gives a definitive answer.

I'm using Firestore as a database for an Unity app. My goal is to only allow that app to write to/read from that database. There is no user login, as the app has no use for it. Everything is working already as far as the reading and writing.

My first question is, do I even need Firebase Authentication for this? Or can the app only read/write if it has the associated GoogleServices.json (android) and PList (iOS) files in when it was built? I don't want unauthorized users to access my databse, and i'm unsure how secure just having the json and plist files are.

My second question is this. I have 2 data nodes in the database, one for reading and the other for writing to the general user of the app. I know how to set up the rules so that's the case. But I do want special execution, say I have a personal app that should be able to read the otherwise write-only node, and write to the otherwise read-only node.

Would I need Firebase Authentication then? I assume I have to make a read exception to use Authentication in the security rules.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You could use a dedicated "App-User" and hardcode the login into the App => The app itself authenticates with the database ... The problem here of course: Everyone could try and decompile the app and would have access to the credentials, except you obfuscate it enough e.g. use some encryptions etc so a potential hacker just gives up at some point .. or not ^^

Answer (score 1):

Question1:
If you do not want unauthorized access to your database, you do need Firebase Auth. Luckily, Firebase Auth has a feature for people like you who don't need to have people log in to your app. It's called Anonymous Authentication, and it essentially works by you signing in users in the back ground without your app's user knowing it. With this, you can restrict database access so that a certain user would not be able to override someone else's data. You can read more about Anonymous Authentication with Unity [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/anonymous-auth).

Question2:
I don't know if the situation you are describing like a admin case, where you as an admin of the app should be able to read/write to the database where normal users should not be allowed, but if that is the case you may use "Custom Claims". With custom claims, you are adding a special key-value pair to your auth token to then use it in security rules. You can read more about custom claims [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the quick reply. I got the anonymous sign-in to work, and I *think* I set up the rules correctly.

I have a document in Firestore called 'organizations', and I want the any user that is signed-in to be able to read it and everything below it, but only write if he's user id is administrator. From the Firestore docs, I think I should set the rules like this:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents 
  {
    match /organizations/{organization=**}
    {
      allow read: if request.auth != null; 
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == "administrator";
    }
}
```

I have a function that runs at the beginning of the app that signs the user in anonymously, which I can confirm works since I can read the user when the task is completed.

However, something isn't working right in the rules.

The app can read the Firestore node whether or not I'm signed in or not. I can comment out the sign-in function, and it will still read the "organization" node. I'm not sure if signing in anonymously does anything at all. Maybe I'm signing in wrong?

Here is my sign-in function:

```
public async Task SignInAnon()
    {
        await FirestoreController.firebaseAuth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync().ContinueWith(task => 
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInAnonymouslyAsync was canceled.");
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInAnonymouslyAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                return;
            }

            GameManager.anonUser = task.Result;
            Debug.Log("Firebase Signed-In as: " + GameManager.anonUser.UserId);
        });
    }
```

anonUser is a static variable initiated elsewhere in the code. Or can I not doing it this way?

EDIT: I'm an idiot. I signed in once and I didn't bother to sign the user out, so I'm treated as signed in even if I comment out the code. :P